# replace all forward slashes in url with one slash

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to replace all multiple forward slashes in an url with single slash. I tried with String `replaceAll()` regex, but it doesn't work.

Example cases:

1. `https://localhost/app//page1` should return as `https://localhost/app/page1`
2. `https://localhost/app//page1//subpage1` should return as `https://localhost/app/page1/subpage1`
3. `//page1//subpage1` should return as `/page1/subpag1`

Comment: show us how you tried

Comment: url.replaceAll("//*","/"); this updates // with single (3rd case in the above list). I dont know how to fix for 1 and 2 cases

Comment: you want to replace all `//` except after `https:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regex with lookbehind like this:

```
(?<!https:)\/\/
```

This will remove `//` only if `https:` is not present before.

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/sM8hC3/1)**

[image]

You can use this **java** code:

```
String url = "https://localhost/app//page1".replaceAll("(?<!https:)\\/\\/", "/");
System.out.println(url);
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to roll your own solution for this. Java provides classes to work with URIs and URLs.

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class URLTest {
    private static final String VICTIM = "https://localhost/app//page1//subpage1";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        URI uri = new URI(VICTIM);
        System.out.println("before: " + uri);
        uri = uri.normalize();
        System.out.println("after:  " + uri);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
before: https://localhost/app//page1//subpage1
after:  https://localhost/app/page1/subpage1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign returned value:

`url = url.replaceAll("//*","/");`

This method doesn't work on passed string directly. It returns new string with replaced parts.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

String value = "https://localhost/app//page1";

String result = value.replaceAll("(//)", "/"));

System.out.println(result);